# Is there a $0$ in the Smith Normal Form?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a PID.

Let $M$ be a $R$-module with generating set $\{m_1, m_2, ..., m_n\}$.

Let $R^{(n)}=\{f\mid f:\{1, 2, ..., n\}\to R\}$ be the free module with basis
$$\{e_i\in R^{(n)}\mid e_i=(0, 0, ..., 0, 1_{i\text{th position}}, 0, ..., 0, 0), ~1\leq i\leq n\}.$$

Define $\phi:R^{(n)}\to M$ by $\phi(e_i)=m_i$.
That is, $\phi\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_i e_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}r_i m_i$.
Then $\phi$ is an onto $R$-module homomorphism.

Since $K=\ker{\phi}$ is a submodule of the free module $R^{(n)}$,
we know that $K$ has a finite **linearly independent** generating set $\{k_1, k_2, ..., k_m\}$,
where $m\leq n$.

Suppose that
$$(k_1, k_2, ..., k_m)=(e_1, e_2, ..., e_n)A.$$
for some $A\in M_{n\times m}(R)$.

The textbook (Jacobson's *Algebra I* and Goodman's *Algebra*) state that 
there exist invertible matrices $P\in M_n(R)$ and $Q\in M_m(R)$
such that
$$PAQ=\text{diag}(\underbrace{d_1, d_2, ..., d_s, 0, ..., 0}_{\min{(n, m)}\text{ terms}}), ~r\leq \min{(n, m)}=m.$$

I have tried some concrete examples, 
for example, 
$M=\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus \Bbb{Z}_3\oplus \Bbb{Z}$ over $\Bbb{Z}$.
But I **can't** find an example which has a $0$ in its smith normal form $\text{diag}(d_1, d_2, ..., d_s, 0, 0, ..., 0)$.

Could someone give an example $\phi$ which has a $0$ in the Smith Normal Form?

**Edit:**
If $A$ is a $m$-by-$n$ matrix
and $a_{ij}=0$ for every $i\neq j$, 
then we write $A=\text{diag}(a_{11}, a_{22}, ..., a_{kk})$, 
where $k=\min{(m, n)}$.
For example, 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}=\text{diag}(a_{11},0).$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & 0 & 0\\
0 & a_{22} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}=\text{diag}(a_{11},a_{22},0).$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a_{22} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}=\text{diag}(a_{11},a_{22},0,0).$$

Comment: The matrix $A$ has rank $m$ (for its columns are linearly independent), so clearly $PAQ$ is also a $n \times m$ matrix of rank $m$. I'm not sure what you mean by $\diag(\ldots)$ for a non-square matrix.

Comment: @arkeet Thank you for your hint. I got it!
If $\{k_1, k_2, ..., k_m\}$ is linearly independent,
then there has no $0$ in $\text{diag}(...)$.
That why I can't find a proper example.
Because I alway choose a linearly independent generating set of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $V=\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus \Bbb{Z}_3\oplus \Bbb{Z}\oplus \Bbb{Z}$
2. Define $\phi:\Bbb{Z}^{(4)}\to V$ by naturally.
3. $K=\ker{\phi}=\{r(2, 0, 0, 0)+s(0, 3, 0, 0)\mid r, s\in \Bbb{Z}\}$
4. $K=\langle (2, 0, 0, 0), (0, 3, 0, 0), (2, 3, 0, 0)\rangle$. (We choose a **Non**-linearly independent generating set of $K$ artificially.)
5. $A=\begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 0 & 2\\
   0 & 3 & 3\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}$
6. $PAQ=\begin{pmatrix}
   -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
   3 & -2 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}\cdot
   \begin{pmatrix}
   2 & 0 & 2\\
   0 & 3 & 3\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}\cdot
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 3 & -1\\
   1 & 2 & -1\\
   0 & 0 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}=
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 6 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   \hline
   0 & 0 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}=
   \text{diag}(1, 6, 0)$.